# What's the htaccess and regex to convert "http://x.com/address.1xxxx" to "http://address.y.com"

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I have a site with about a thousand pages in google's index - only those pages don't exist on that server anymore and need to point to another site.  I need them to 301 redirect over to the other server where they will exist as subdomains instead of pages.

old page
"http://x.com/address.1xxxx"

new page
"http://address.y.com"

where x.com is the old server and y.com is the new server. Also, .1xxxx is one of a couple hundred different zipcodes all beginning with 1 - ie, 10010 - that is no longer a part of the new URL and need to be removed. Additionally the 'address' page of the page name is a street address with dots instead of spaces - like '123.main.st.anytown.ny"

What should my .htaccess look like to parse all the incoming page requests and send them over to the other site with a 301 permanent redirect?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should work. If the zip codes are not all 5 digits, change the `[0-9]{4}` to `[0-9]+`.

```
# Rewrite requests to domain x.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^x\.com$
# Group the set before the final dot, followed by 5 digits starting with 1
# and place the group as $1 before .y.com
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9\.-]+)\.(1[0-9]{4})$ http://$1.y.com [NC,L,R=301]
```

Comment: thanks for your response michael - i ended up using Ulrich's response above successfully but i'll try yours if i run into trouble - thanks so much!

Comment: @SeanKean Whichever solution you choose, be sure to mark the answer as accepted by clicking the gray checkmark beside it. And welcome to Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to the .htaccess file in the root directory of site x.com

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/address\.1[0-9]{4,4}$ [NC]
RewriteRule . http://address.y.com [NC,L,R=301]
```

if address is not literally address but a variable, then use below instead

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.+)\.1[0-9]{4,4}$ [NC]
RewriteRule . http://%1.y.com [NC,L,R=301]
```

Comment: wow - this is my first time using stack exchange and this perfectly solved the problem i've been working on all day in 2 minutes - thanks so much Ulrich, i really appreciate it!